# I/OpenJPEG(18753): [INFO] No decoded area parameters, set the decoded area to the whole image. How to solve it?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, flutter-platform-channel

I add some native function to my Flutter project and get this error when I call it:

```html
I/OpenJPEG(18753): [INFO] Start to read j2k main header (111).
I/OpenJPEG(18753): [INFO] Main header has been correctly decoded.
I/OpenJPEG(18753): [INFO] No decoded area parameters, set the decoded area to the whole image
I/OpenJPEG(18753): [INFO] Header of tile 1 / 1 has been read.
I/OpenJPEG(18753): [INFO] Stream reached its end !


 PlatformException(error, Unsupported value: 'android.graphics.Bitmap@8a5b1cc' of type 'class android.graphics.Bitmap', null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value
: 'android.graphics.Bitmap@8a5b1cc' of type 'class android.graphics.Bitmap'
I/flutter (20654):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:292)
I/flutter (20654):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeSuccessEnvelope(StandardMethodCodec.java:59)
I/flutter (20654):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:267)
I/flutter (20654):      at com.yapeal.security.MainActivity.convertJp2(MainActivity.kt:163)
I/flutter (20654):      at com.yapeal.security.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:70)
I/flutter (20654):      at com.yapeal.security.MainActivity.lambda$Sgujey3khZ1hmf7McHG_B6lCGlU(Unknown Source:0)
I/flutter (20654):      at com.yapeal.security.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$Sgujey3khZ1hmf7McHG_B6lCGlU.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:2)
I/flutter (20654):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.j
```

Here is my code in Kotlin:

```html
private fun convertJp2(list: List<Any>, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        val inputStream: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(list.get(0) as ByteArray, 0, list.get(1) as Int)

        var image = JP2Decoder(inputStream).decode()
        result.success(image)
    }
```

I have no experience with Kotlin, so I have no idea how to solve this problem. Moreover, I didn't find a similar problem in google.....

Answer (score 1):

`StandardMessageCodec`, which is used by the `MethodChannel` doesn't support `Bitmap` out of the box (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html).

You can extend the `StandardMessageCodec` and override `writeValue` to support it (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#custom-channels-and-codecs)

Here is an example how `cloud_firestore` uses its own codec to extend the functionality:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/utils/firestore_message_codec.dart

```
  @override
  void writeValue(WriteBuffer buffer, dynamic value) {
    if (value is DateTime) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kDateTime);
      buffer.putInt64(value.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    } else if (value is Timestamp) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kTimestamp);
      buffer.putInt64(value.seconds);
      buffer.putInt32(value.nanoseconds);
    } else if (value is GeoPoint) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kGeoPoint);
      buffer.putFloat64(value.latitude);
      buffer.putFloat64(value.longitude);
    } else if (value is DocumentReferencePlatform) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kDocumentReference);
      writeValue(buffer, value.firestore);
      writeValue(buffer, value.path);
    } else if (value is Blob) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kBlob);
      writeSize(buffer, value.bytes.length);
      buffer.putUint8List(value.bytes);
    } else if (value is FieldValuePlatform) {
      MethodChannelFieldValue delegate = FieldValuePlatform.getDelegate(value);
      final int code = _kFieldValueCodes[delegate.type]!;
      buffer.putUint8(code);
      if (delegate.value != null) writeValue(buffer, delegate.value);
    } else if (value is FieldPathType) {
      final int code = _kFieldPathCodes[value]!;
      buffer.putUint8(code);
    } else if (value is FieldPath) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kFieldPath);
      writeSize(buffer, value.components.length);
      for (final String item in value.components) {
        writeValue(buffer, item);
      }
    } else if (value is MethodChannelFirebaseFirestore) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kFirestoreInstance);
      writeValue(buffer, value.app.name);
      writeValue(buffer, value.settings);
    } else if (value is MethodChannelQuery) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kFirestoreQuery);
      writeValue(buffer, <String, dynamic>{
        'firestore': value.firestore,
        'path': value.path,
        'isCollectionGroup': value.isCollectionGroupQuery,
        'parameters': value.parameters,
      });
    } else if (value is Settings) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kFirestoreSettings);
      writeValue(buffer, value.asMap);
    } else if (value == double.nan) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kNaN);
    } else if (value == double.infinity) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kInfinity);
    } else if (value == double.negativeInfinity) {
      buffer.putUint8(_kNegativeInfinity);
    } else {
      super.writeValue(buffer, value);
    }
  }
```

Used like:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/982bdfb5fbfae4a68e1af6ab62a9bd762891b217/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart

```
  /// The [FirebaseApp] instance to which this [FirebaseDatabase] belongs.
  ///
  /// If null, the default [FirebaseApp] is used.
  /// The [MethodChannel] used to communicate with the native plugin
  static MethodChannel channel = const MethodChannel(
    'plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore',
    StandardMethodCodec(FirestoreMessageCodec()),
  );

  /// The [EventChannel] used for query snapshots
  static EventChannel querySnapshotChannel(String id) {
    return EventChannel(
      'plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore/query/$id',
      const StandardMethodCodec(FirestoreMessageCodec()),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but do I need to change something on the Android side? Because when I made a custom message codec, I got an exception: No implementation found for method convertJp2 on channel .....

Comment: Ah. Yes. Here are the two files fitting to the ones above: [Plugin](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/45e27201480088fab71af60963001baeae61d80d/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java) and [Codec](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/982bdfb5fbfae4a68e1af6ab62a9bd762891b217/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java#L33)